# Como fechar uma "pasta"

Tags: delphi, cmd

Tenho um projecto em Delphi 2010 que quando clico em um botão abre um directório, este é o código:

```
DirFolder := 'C:\teste';
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(DirFolder), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Abre isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deixo a questão, é possível quando fechar o projecto também fechar essa pasta?

Comment: quando você diz pasta, se refere a pasta do Windows?

Comment: sim pasta do windows, este é o directório dela:
"C:\teste"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isto, uma delas é usar a função [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) para retornar o identificador da janela através do nome da classe ou título.

Para fechar, você pode usar a função [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) e usar o sinal [`WM_CLOSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms632617(v=vs.85).aspx) para indicar que a aplicação deve ser finalizada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Janela: THandle;
begin
  Janela := FindWindow(nil, 'teste'); // "teste" é o título da janela
  if Janela > 0 then // Se conseguir encontrar a janela
     SendMessage(Janela, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: obrigado pela explicação, era isso mesmo que precisava!